# Encrypt a string with a password in ruby

Tags: ruby, encryption

I'd like to get some input from a user and encrypt it with a password. For example, a user gives me:

```
String: 'Whackabad'
Password 'Holycrap'
```

I'd like to store their string, encrypted, but be able to decrypt the string again when the user enters their password. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`encrypted_strings`](https://github.com/pluginaweek/encrypted_strings) gem:

```
data = 'Whackabad'
password = 'Holycrap'
encrypted = data.encrypt(:symmetric, :algorithm => 'des-ecb', :password => password) 
# => "N6gLAAL9d9lRjHUbh54Ctw==\n"

encrypted.decrypt(:symmetric, :algorithm => 'des-ecb', :password => password) 
# => "Whackabad"
```

This solution does *not* encrypt nor store the password anywhere - it encrypts that data, and only someone who *knows* the password will be able to decrypt the data.

This is a good solution if you don't want anyone (including the admin of the site) to be able to decrypt the data without having the correct password.

Answer (score -1):

Use [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise). This is a full authentication solution.